# NodeJS - Find a given file by name and ext regardless of location, from inside a working directory (Closed)

Tags: node.js

How do I search for a specific file by name and extension in a working directory, regardless of the file's path from inside that working directory?

For example, if we are searching for `foo.txt` inside our first working directory, but it's located within a file path like the example below

```
workDir/folder2/is/foo/directory/foo.txt
```

Then say for further example, we want to then search for `foo.txt` inside our second working directory, but the file is located within a different file path like below

```
workDir/folder11/this/way/to/foo.txt
```

How would I find `foo.txt` regardless of the file's path, inside a working directory?

I am Using the below JavaScript code in my NodeJS project's **controller.js** file to try and achieve this.

**NOTE: In real-time, every working directory this would be used on, would be named differently**

**controller.js**

```js
var fooPath = GetFooPath(data, path.join(workDir, "folder11/"));
            if (fooPath == -1) {
                console.log("Cannot find the foo file!");
                return;
            }
```

Comment: You have to look for the file recursively in every subdirectory, using [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback).

Comment: So in other words I would have to specify every first folder to enter in order to achieve this, `folder2` `folder3` etc, then search for the file inside of those directories? Sorry I am still new to JavaScript and NodeJS

Comment: You have to write a recursive function that searches for the file in a given directory. You call this function initially with the root directory, but it calls itself with the direct subdirectories of the given directory.

Comment: Yeah so I'm still new to JS, so you'd have to give me an example on that with the code snippet above if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use globbing

```
glob("absolute/path/to/workDir/**/*.txt", options, 
    function (error, files) {
   // files is an array of filenames.
   // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
   // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
   // error is an error object or null.
 })
```

[NPM glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

Comment: I'll give this one a try and see if it works.

Comment: No this doesn't seem to want to work for me, tried as much as I could and still nothing, any other suggestions???

Comment: This should work. What paths have you looked for ? What is your glob string ?

Comment: I specify `glob(workDir` which gives an absolute path to the working directory I do believe, using `node-homedir` & `path`. The problem after this is I still need to specify `folder11` or `folder3` in order to find the correct file I need

Comment: I could be doing it wrong, I have stated I am still fairly new to JS & node, if possible could you show me using my code snippet above sir???

Comment: Your glob would look like "workDir/**/foo.txt"
** means every nested directory from now (workDir)
* would match every file, combined "*.txt" would match every .txt file, "**/foo.txt" would match every foo.txt file inside "workDir"

Comment: Ahh I see, yeah I was definitely doing it wrong I'll give this a shot

Comment: No, can't seem to get it to work, unfortunately, I don't know why

Comment: Wait no, after mucking around a bit, I noticed my errors and yes this works GREAT! thanks man!